# Independent events from any other

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P$) probability space, how can I show that

$\forall A\in \mathcal{N}=\left\{ A\in\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{P}(A)=0,or\,\, \mathbb{P}(A)=1 \right\}\Rightarrow$

$\forall E\in\Omega$ I have $\mathbb{P}(A\cap E)=\mathbb{P}(E)$ if $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap E)=0$ if $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ ?

Comment: The mathematical sentence in your question is logically unsound. One simply cannot write $$\forall x\in X\implies Q(x)$$ for some assertion $Q(x)$ depending on $x$. Reformulating this to reach a correct statement would be a very learning experience, I am sure. (There are also other problems in the post but first things go first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any events $A$ and $E$ we can write
$$ \mathbb{P}(E)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap E)+\mathbb{P}(A^c\cap E) $$
If $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(A^c)=1-1=0$ and 
$$ 0\leq \mathbb{P}(A^c\cap E)\leq \mathbb{P}(A^c)=0 $$
so $\mathbb{P}(E)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap E)$.

Similarly, if $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ then $0\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap E)\leq \mathbb{P}(A)=0$, hence $\mathbb{P}(A\cap E)=0$ as well.